# Custom User Profile for New Users

Tags: python, django

```
{% if user.userprofile.profile %}
    <img src="{{ user.userprofile.profile.url }}" />
{% else %}
    <img src="something" />
{% endif %}
```

If user don't have a profile picture then I wants to give them the Profile picture of very First user (means id=1).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the 1st user picture url in return statement of the template

In your views.py

```
return render(request, 'your_template_url', {'user': user, 'pic_url': pic_url})
```

In your templates

```
{% if user.userprofile.profile %}
    <img src="{{user.userprofile.profile.url}}" />
{% else %}
    <img src="{{pic_url}}" />
{% endif %}
```